# packer でエラーが発生した場合に、ビルド中のコンテナ・インスタンスを削除しないようにするには？

Tags: packer

packer build の provisioner でエラーが発生した場合には、異常終了したという結果を残し、イメージをビルドするのに使われていたコンテナ・インスタンスは削除されます。

これだと、何が原因で落ちたのかが、標準出力の情報以上の情報を取得することができずに、下手すると途方にくれてしまいます。

何が原因かを調査したいため、この異常終了の際にもコンテナ・インスタンスを削除しないようにしたいです。

これは、どうやったら実現できますでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ついさきほど、 https://github.com/mitchellh/packer/pull/3885 が master にマージされたようです。

```
-on-error=[cleanup|abort|ask]
```

オプションで、指定が可能だそうです。